# How can I close a video with MediaElement?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a MediaElement, and with a click of a button, I open a video

```
<Button x:Name="VideoTour" Click="VideoTour_Click"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,14,0,0" Foreground="#FF5ACB2F" Background="{x:Null}">
        <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="../Assets/Movie.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
        </Button.Content>
</Button> 

 <MediaElement x:Name="PlayTour" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  Source="{Binding URLtour}" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Width="260" Height="250"/>
```

When the video has opened, I would like to submit a button to close the MediaElement video, and set the Visibility property Collpased, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new button and subscribe **Click** event where you will stop your video

```
        PlayTour.Stop();
```

I think, you can handle how determine Visibility state for your buttons